# I need my navbar to stop overlapping over the content

Tags: html, css

The content begins to appear on the page overlapped with the navbar, I cannot really figure out where can I solve this.
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css">
  <script src="s.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<header>
    <nav id="navbar" class="">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="home.html"><i class="fa fa-angellist"></i> Logo</a>
          </div>
      
          <ul id="menu">
              <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="mate.html">Matematica</a></li>
              <li><a href="rom.html">Limba romana</a></li>
              <li><a href="info.html">Informatica</a></li>
              <li><a href="contacte.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
      <div class="menuIcon">
        <span class="icon icon-bars"></span>
        <span class="icon icon-bars overlay"></span>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="overlay-menu">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
</header>
<body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box">A</div>
        <div class="box">B</div>
        <div class="box">C</div>
        <div class="box">D</div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    background: rgb(250, 250, 250) url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/);
    font-family: Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  header{
    z-index: 1;
  }
  a {
    color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  
  /*======================================================
                            Navbar
    ======================================================*/
  #navbar {
    background: white;
    color: rgb(13, 26, 38);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 10;
    
  }
  
  .nav-wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
  } @media(max-width: 768px) {
      .nav-wrapper {
        width: 90%;
      }
    } @media(max-width: 638px) {
        .nav-wrapper {
          width: 100%;
        }
      } 
  
  
  .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 28px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  } @media(max-width: 768px) {
      .logo {
  /*       margin-left: 5px; */
      }
    }
  
  #navbar ul {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    /* margin-right: 14px; */
    margin-top: -2px;
    text-align: right;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
  } @media(max-width: 640px) {
      #navbar ul {
        display: none;
      }
    } @media(orientation: landscape) {
        #navbar ul {
          display: inline-block;
        }
      }
  
  #navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  #navbar li a {
    color: rgb(13, 26, 38);
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  
  #navbar li a:hover {
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(28, 121, 184);
    color: rgb(28, 121, 184);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  
  /* Animated Bottom Line */
  #navbar li a:before, #navbar li a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
  }
  
  #navbar li a:before {
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  
  #navbar li a:after {
    background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
    right: 0;
    /* transition: width 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1); */
  }
  
  #navbar li a:hover:before {
    background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier((0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1));
  }
  
  #navbar li a:hover:after {
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    /* transition: 0s; */
  }
  
  
  
  /*======================================================
                      Mobile Menu Menu Icon
    ======================================================*/
  @media(max-width: 640px) {
    .menuIcon {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      right: 15px;
      top: 20px;
      height: 23px;
      width: 27px;
      z-index: 12;
    }
  
    /* Icon Bars */
    .icon-bars {
      background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
      position: absolute;
      left: 1px;
      top: 45%;
      height: 2px;
      width: 20px;
      -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
      transition: 0.4s;
    } 
  
    .icon-bars::before {
      background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: -8px;
      height: 2px;
      width: 20px;
  /*     -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease 0.3s;
      transition: top 0.2s ease 0.3s; */
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s width 0.4s;
      transition: 0.3s width 0.4s;
    }
  
    .icon-bars::after {
      margin-top: 0px;
      background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: -8px;
      height: 2px;
      width: 20px;
  /*     -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease 0.3s;
      transition: top 0.2s ease 0.3s; */
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s width 0.4s;
      transition: 0.3s width 0.4s;
    }
  
    /* Bars Shadows */
    .icon-bars.overlay {
      background: rgb(97, 114, 129);
      background: rgb(183, 199, 211);
      width: 20px;
      animation: middleBar 3s infinite 0.5s;
      -webkit-animation: middleBar 3s infinite 0.5s;
    } @keyframes middleBar {
        0% {width: 0px}
        50% {width: 20px}
        100% {width: 0px}
      } @-webkit-keyframes middleBar {
          0% {width: 0px}
          50% {width: 20px}
          100% {width: 0px}
        }
  
    .icon-bars.overlay::before {
      background: rgb(97, 114, 129);
      background: rgb(183, 199, 211);
      width: 10px;
      animation: topBar 3s infinite 0.2s;
      -webkit-animation: topBar 3s infinite 0s;
    } @keyframes topBar {
        0% {width: 0px}
        50% {width: 10px}
        100% {width: 0px}
      } @-webkit-keyframes topBar {
          0% {width: 0px}
          50% {width: 10px}
          100% {width: 0px}
        }
  
    .icon-bars.overlay::after {
      background: rgb(97, 114, 129);
      background: rgb(183, 199, 211);
      width: 15px;
      animation: bottomBar 3s infinite 1s;
      -webkit-animation: bottomBar 3s infinite 1s;
    } @keyframes bottomBar {
        0% {width: 0px}
        50% {width: 15px}
        100% {width: 0px}
      } @-webkit-keyframes bottomBar {
          0% {width: 0px}
          50% {width: 15px}
          100% {width: 0px}
        }
  
  
    /* Toggle Menu Icon */
    .menuIcon.toggle .icon-bars {
      top: 5px;
      transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0) rotate(135deg);
      transition-delay: 0.1s;
      transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    }
  
    .menuIcon.toggle .icon-bars::before {
      top: 0;
      transition-delay: 0.1s;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    .menuIcon.toggle .icon-bars::after {
      top: 10px;
      transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0) rotate(-270deg);
      transition-delay: 0.1s;
      transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    }
  
    .menuIcon.toggle .icon-bars.overlay {
      width: 20px;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0s ease 0s;
      transition: all 0s ease 0s;
    }
  }
  
  
  /*======================================================
                     Responsive Mobile Menu 
    ======================================================*/
  .overlay-menu {
    background: lightblue;
    color: rgb(13, 26, 38);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  
  .overlay-menu ul, .overlay-menu li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .overlay-menu li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
  /*   opacity: 0; */
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
  /*   -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: 0.2s opacity 0.2s ease-out; */
  }
  
  .overlay-menu li a:hover,
  .overlay-menu li a:active {
    color: rgb(28, 121, 184);
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
  }

  .timetable {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: ". week" "time content";
    grid-template-columns: 120px;
    grid-template-rows: 60px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
 }
 .timetable .week-names {
  grid-area: week;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.timetable .week-names > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 0 0 black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: large;
}
.timetable .time-interval {
  grid-area: time;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
  font-size: 14px;
}
.timetable .time-interval > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 0 black;
}
.timetable .content {
  grid-area: content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
.timetable .content > div {
  box-shadow: inset 3px 0 0 black, inset 0 3px 0 0 black;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: large;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-row: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
.container .box {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The fixed attribute doesn't affect the layout of the rest of the page,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Since you have a fixed height for your fixed element, you can add

```
margin-top: 60px;
```

to your primary container element to add in the space that the fixed element would normally have taken.

Comment: Yes, but then on other pages I will have to scroll in order to reach the bottom instead of the container appearing full on the page.